# HTML + Chrome help having a form in the page space

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a input box somewhere on the screen in chrome, not attached to extension button like a normal popup,

it also needs to be running all the time so the user doesnt need to click the extension button to open it, for example so they do not have to come out of fullscreen.

What i have so far since im not great at html or java just a simple form

What i have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXsXx.png

What i want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4STT.png

I would also like to control the position of the form but from what i have above doesnt seem as if i will be able,

Sorry if its a bit vague but anything helps!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can't be done in Chrome. This is by design. If web content could display itself outside the boundaries of the browser tab's content area, then users might be confused who was presenting it. Confusion is just the beginning of that problem: if web/extension content could masquerade as a system or browser-level alert, then that content could trick the user into doing something dangerous.

If you need a presence outside of a browser tab, your options are a native app or Chrome App.

Comment: Thanks, i was wondering why what i am trying to create hasn't already been done, this answers that

Comment: If it answers your question, then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the input box to be displayed on the page you could use content script - then it would appear as you presented.